# Java: InetAddress#isReachable only works in IDE

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, connection

I'm trying to check for internet connection in my Java app.

I tried, as suggested on several posts here on SO, to go with:

```
InetAddress#isReachable(timeOut);
```

However, this doesn't seem to work all the time: If I run the code in Eclipse, it works. Outside of eclipse (.jar), it doesn't work and always returns offline.
Is there some limitation that I am not aware of?
I have tried running the jar as administrator as several people suggested on other answers, nothing changed.
I'm running it on Windows 10, the JVM has full internet access and firewall permission.

Comment: Only tips: Can you access that IP address from command line, without any Java involved? E.g: ping? Have you checked the Network Connection settings in your eclipse? May be it has something special setup...

Comment: Yes I can access it, there is no special setup..